# Can we reopen this?

Tags: support

[Replace pneumatic thermostat without running new wires](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/236417/41478)

While yes, *in general* shopping advice is not good, *in specifics* the argument that they tend to become obsolete quickly in this case doesn't hold much water -- there are *extremely* few products in the field and none has been introduced since 2012 and since these upgrade an already obsolete, ancient system to current it's not exactly the hotspot of innovation. Could we please make an exception and keep this open in the extremely unlikely case more happens?

Comment: Where would we draw the line? And if someone answers the question with a link to a vendor's website, how would we differentiate between a helpful answer and a spammer pushing their product?

Comment: @BMitch no links, very easy. I carefully included none.

Comment: Spam doesn't require a link.

Answer (score 1):

The *question* seems to be about how to handle upgrading a pneumatic thermostat with an electric one (or if it's even possible). That does seem to be on-topic at least in terms of topicality (though I can't say if it is on-topic in terms of having enough detail/specificity to be answered... but since it has at least one answer by someone else, chances are that it is answerable.

However, your *answer* reads pretty strongly like a shopping list recommendation. I would recommend you rewrite that answer to talk less about the price and availability of specific units (you literally point out what shopping site to buy two particular *units* and what each one is going for... that's not what the DIY.SE site is for), and focus more on the type of thermostat that solves this problem and how they work.

Think of the "Ask This Old House" video series on YouTube... they take bite-sized problems about DIY, show you products (without recommending a specific brand or mentioning a specific price or store name where you can get them), and explain how they work/how something gets installed/put together, all in a few minutes. A brand might be visible or even mentioned, but it's typically just that... mentioned. Not highlighted.

You can always provide an example of a specific tool that solves a problem in your answer, but that answer should focus on solving the problem, not doing OP's shopping for them (even if you are also OP).

(N.B. I personally don't have enough reputation to cast a reopen vote, for the record)